# Setlength in Delphi 10.2.3 for array like types

Tags: arrays, delphi

Although I found some postings concerning the subject setlength I couldn't find out a solution for my problem:

With the code below - which is part of a much bigger program -

```
type TVektor2=array[20] of extended;
      TElement2=array[20] of String;

Procedure Sort_Shell2(
 element1X: TElement2; zahlX: TVektor2; var Element2X : TElement2;
 var zahl2X : TVektor2);
var
  bis, i, j, k, min : LongInt;    l, laenge  : single;
  h,s,w,h1,h2, ElemX: string;
  e : array[20] of String;  
begin
laenge := 5;   // just an example 

SetLength(Element1X, 3); /// Error 
 //DynArraySetlength(e,l,1); /// how?

  bis := High(e);
  k := bis shr 1;// div 2
  while (k > 0) do
  begin
    for i := 0 to (bis - k) do
    begin
      j := i;
      h1 := e[j];     //I use this because before I had an Acces violation
      h2 := e[j + k]; // using directly e[j] := e[j+k]; 
      while (j >= 0) and (h1 > h2) do
      begin
        h := h1;
         l:=zahlx[j]; //str(l:5:3,S);showmessage(h + s);
        e[j] :=e[j + k];
        zahlx[j] := zahlx[j+ k];
        e[j + k] := h;
        zahlx[j+ k]:=l;
        if j > k then
          Dec(j, k)
        else
          j := 0;
      end; // {end while]
    end; // { end for}
    k := k shr 1; // div 2
  end;  // {end while}
   Element2x:=e;  zahl2x :=zahlx;
  end;
```

I get the error 'incompatible types' if I try the setlength command like this. 
I tried - with a for next loop -to attribute to each position of the static  array (with 20 entries) or also to the correponding dynamic array and then to use setlength.
But it didn't work. Is there some casting possible to transform TElement2 to an array ? (since it is already an array!)

Why isn't it possible to use a simple static array[1..20] of strings = a, set for each  position a[i] = TElement2[i] and use setlength(a,5)?

If I use DynArraySetLength(Pointer, typeInfo,dimCnt, lengthVec) what must I use for these variables? 
I don't know nearly anything about Pointers and I have no idea for such problem what parameters I must use to get an array of a given length starting with the given TElement2 array. By the way, in general, is it a good idea to use dynamic arrays?

By the way there might also be an error in this sorting routine because it doesn't work well...

Can any one help me?

Comment: You've declared the base type as a static arrray with only 20 elements (`TElement2=array[20] of String;`). That means it's size is fixed at 20 elements, and you can't change that at runtime. Dynamic arrays can be resized with SetLength, but not static arrays. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays)

Comment: This isn't your real code. The code here fails at this point `TVektor2 = array [20] of extended` with the error: `E2029 '..' expected but ']' found`. What is your real code? Beyond that, `SetLength` is for use with dynamic arrays. Did you read the documentation for dynamic arrays? If not, why not?

Comment: @KenWhite Nope, it doesn't mean that. That declaration is a syntax error.

Comment: - *"Why isn't it possible to use a simple static array[1..20] ... ... and use setlength(a,5)?"* - Because then it wouldn't be static.

Comment: FWIW, ˋDynArraySetLengthˋ shouldn‘t be used unless you really, really know what you are doing. It requires you to pass type info. ˋSetLengthˋ internally calls this. The type info is provided by the compiler. But don‘t call ˋDynArraySetLengthˋ directly.

Comment: FWIW, to learn about pointers read my article about them: [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: Or don't learn about pointers because you don't need them

Comment: Thanks Ken and David , I thought I could use Setlength for static arrays. So to say to cut them. In several postings I saw that it has been used, I didn't notize that these were dynamic arrays..

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a Dynamic Array in Delphi you have to declare an array like this:

```
TElement2=array of String;
```

and not `TElement2=array[20] of String` or `TElement2=array[1..20] of String;`

If you declare `TElement2` that way then `SetLength(element1X, 3);` is going to work.

moreover when you assign at the bottom of the code

```
Element2x:=e;
```

it's not going to compile unless both variable aren't declared of the same type:

```
e : TElement2;
```